# shr raid drives with crashed nas OS (synology)

Tags: mount, backup, raid

I have two disks which I used as SHR (synology hybrid raid) in synology NAS. After an update the OS crashed without ability to use reset option. apparently this is known as white screen of death.

I'm looking for a way to access the data to transfer it to a back-up disk. Unfortunately I have no back-up now.

Synology posted a solution to mount the disks on a PC under Ubuntu.

I followed all the steps, except the "postfix configuration - no configuration" option as it did not appear during installation.

I have the following disk info when plugged in via USB (have no desktop available so USB is my only option for now)

Both disks are visible under gparted (sdb and sdc)
Both disks are symmetrical, so info below for sdb counts also for sdc
partitioning:

- `/dev/sdb1` (2,37 GiB)
- `/dev/sdb2` (2,00 GiB)
  127,12 MB unallocated
- Extended partition: `/dev/sdb3` (927,01 GiB)
  7,80 MB Unallocated
- /dev/sdb5 926,91 GiB)
  94,12 MB unallocated
  6,91 unallocated

sdb 1,2,3, and 5 are all linux raid as file configuration

Extended partition is LBA

There is no sdb 4

sdb5 has mount point `/dev/md2`

When I ran `mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay` the disks responded physically both at the same time (as expected when both disk should mount)

After inspection gparted showed a extra disk `/dev/md2` with only one 926,91 GiB partion of lvm pv2 files system. Exactly as the drive size under in the synology NAS. So it seems that it all should've worked, but no extra drive under nautilus or in the mnt folder. also a little key with `/dev/md2` under gparted and no option to mount (probably as it is already mounted).

Is there another way to excess this (mounted?) md2 partition?

Is the SHR (synology hybrid raid) file system an issue here? It is probably different then common raid. They don't mention anything about this though, not as far as I know.

Hoping for tips or help on how to access the data.

`sudo lvs`:

```
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 114,84g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----   3,90g                                                    
  lv     vg1000    -wi-a----- 926,90g
```

`sudo vgs`:

```
LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 114,84g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----   3,90g                                                    
  lv     vg1000    -wi-a----- 926,90g
```

`sudo pvs`:

```
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 114,84g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----   3,90g                                                    
  lv     vg1000    -wi-a----- 926,90g
```

`sudo pvdisplay`:

```
  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               /dev/md2  
  VG Name               vg1000  
  PV Size               926,91 GiB / not usable 3,81 MiB  
  Allocatable           yes (but full)  
  PE Size               4,00 MiB  
  Total PE              237287  
  Free PE               0  
  Allocated PE          237287  
  PV UUID               BgEiR6-dOhF-POyb-0nVE-GMc1-WW8c-QxWXpc  
   
  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt  
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg  
  PV Size               118,76 GiB / not usable 0     
  Allocatable           yes   
  PE Size               4,00 MiB  
  Total PE              30403  
  Free PE               5  
  Allocated PE          30398  
  PV UUID               hQ16w8-eBos-edQ5-sF1s-CV0q-UB2x-nIIHKf
```

`sudo lvdisplay`

```
  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/vg1000/lv  
  LV Name                lv  
  VG Name                vg1000  
  LV UUID                G40w9j-sqL1-6e7e-1i9g-PcPA-7mo6-9W69Mr  
  LV Write Access        read/write  
  LV Creation host, time ,   
  LV Status              available  
  # open                 0  
  LV Size                926,90 GiB  
  Current LE             237287  
  Segments               1  
  Allocation             inherit  
  Read ahead sectors     auto  
  - currently set to     256  
  Block device           253:4  
   
  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/root  
  LV Name                root  
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg  
  LV UUID                iODJJk-iDeM-5eiy-mGGK-Z2Wj-aJsJ-b9nPNL  
  LV Write Access        read/write  
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-02-03 22:35:31 +0100  
  LV Status              available  
  # open                 1  
  LV Size                114,84 GiB  
  Current LE             29400  
  Segments               1  
  Allocation             inherit  
  Read ahead sectors     auto  
  - currently set to     256  
  Block device           253:1  
     
  --- Logical volume ---  
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1  
  LV Name                swap_1  
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg  
  LV UUID                xHrGFf-GHaB-W4jc-VYJm-e3WT-gkhF-lXigfM  
  LV Write Access        read/write  
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2017-02-03 22:35:31 +0100  
  LV Status              available  
  # open                 1  
  LV Size                3,90 GiB  
  Current LE             998  
  Segments               1  
  Allocation             inherit  
  Read ahead sectors     auto  
  - currently set to     256  
  Block device           253:2
```

`sudo vgdisplay`:

```
  --- Volume group ---  
  VG Name               vg1000  
  System ID               
  Format                lvm2  
  Metadata Areas        1  
  Metadata Sequence No  2  
  VG Access             read/write  
  VG Status             resizable  
  MAX LV                0  
  Cur LV                1  
  Open LV               0  
  Max PV                0  
  Cur PV                1  
  Act PV                1  
  VG Size               926,90 GiB  
  PE Size               4,00 MiB  
  Total PE              237287  
  Alloc PE / Size       237287 / 926,90 GiB  
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0     
  VG UUID               owLxtE-2AEt-yTQX-VyGf-gdkz-u5E8-afGETg  
   
  --- Volume group ---  
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg  
  System ID               
  Format                lvm2  
  Metadata Areas        1  
  Metadata Sequence No  3  
  VG Access             read/write  
  VG Status             resizable  
  MAX LV                0  
  Cur LV                2  
  Open LV               2  
  Max PV                0  
  Cur PV                1  
  Act PV                1  
  VG Size               118,76 GiB  
  PE Size               4,00 MiB  
  Total PE              30403  
  Alloc PE / Size       30398 / 118,74 GiB  
  Free  PE / Size       5 / 20,00 MiB  
  VG UUID               xUCkb6-bk95-bacK-HlIc-IAIv-6rC5-43ymwu
```

Hope this is a bit informative

Comment: It looks like there's a LVM between the RAID physical volume and any actual filesystem - have you tried probing that with the various LVM2 utilities (`sudo pvs`, `sudo vgs`, `sudo lvs` or their `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay`  `lvdisplay` equivalents)?

Comment: didn't know what a lvm was so i looked it up, and i think you are right. so i intended to started probing with your hints. which i didn't do as being unaware of the option.  but unfortunately something unpleasant happened, well 3 thing but most likely related.  1) the drives now show as sde and sdd instead of sdb and sdc. also 2) a libparted error upon opening gparted (input/output error upon reading /dev/md2) and 3 the "mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay" couldn't be performed again.

Comment: tried to remove it following the options here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=884556 but i get an error:   mdadm: Cannot get exclusive access to /dev/md2:Perhaps a running process, mounted filesystem or active volume group? and still sdd and sde.  so i couldn't probe tonight.  do realise it will not be simple to remove the md2. for now but also once i recovered the data. if that will happen. ps: didn't see md2 running fdisk -l

Comment: Please **do not** try to "remove" the RAID - just run `sudo lvs` and add the output to your question

Comment: oke... ourput: 

[sudo] password for matt: 
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert  
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 114,84g                                                      
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----   3,90g

Comment: but this is without the disks connected. did connect just the one by accident and that showed actual md2, but anallocated. got to work now. will restart after work again and and run the command and reply again.

Comment: with disks (in the right order and with proper md2 "mount" as the first time. so i can return to this state!  
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 114,84g                                                    
  swap_1 ubuntu-vg -wi-ao----   3,90g                                                    
  lv     vg1000    -wi-a----- 926,90g

Comment: sudo vgs:   VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  ubuntu-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 118,76g 20,00m
  vg1000      1   1   0 wz--n- 926,90g     0
sudo pvs;   /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  118,76g 20,00m
  /dev/md2               vg1000    lvm2 a--  926,90g     0

Comment: i think the rest give all same sort of info, if you would like me to post anyone specific just say so, just don't wanna spam with redundant info. 
something that is probably clear to you after this info but today pointpoint under gparted of md2 is vg1000. and filesysytem lvm2 pv. not sure why this is different. because i tried to remove the raid settings under ubuntu?

Comment: oeps add to question. sorry, i will.

Comment: So it looks like your data is likely in logical volume `/dev/vg1000/lv` which (provided it contains a filesystem that the live system understands) you should be able to mount either via that link or via the device mapper link `/dev/mapper/vg1000-lv` e.g. `sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv /mnt`

Comment: mounted and copying.. Steeldriver i do not know who you are but am you eternally greatfull! thank you very much!

Comment: just one more question. once i have copied and controlled that data i will start re-using the disks. One as back up one as extra disk in the nas.

how do i properly unmount the raid drive and how do i deleted the raid from the system. as last time it didn't work (thankfully) but this time i would like it to be more succesfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steeldrivers suggestion worked perfectly!

```
sudo mount /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv /mnt
```

still unmounting never got fixed, but got it all copied over the network and disks were formatted so, that got that solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on LVM or mdadm but here's what I did to solve a related problem on Ubuntu 18.

A single hard drive SHR attached trough USB-SATA adapter. The system tries to automatically set the RAID volume, but something goes wrong:

If I try to assemble:

```
mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay

mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md/DiskStation:2
mdadm: giving up.
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

or `mount`:

```
mount /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv /mnt/
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv.
```

I have checked and the system already mapped a `/dev/mdXXX` to the SHR drive. So:

```
dmsetup remove /dev/mapper/vg1000-lv

mdadm --stop /dev/mdXXX
```

And after it's possible to retry to assemble with mdadm:

```
mdadm -Asf && vgchange -ay
```

The mount reference is under `/media/xxxxx/volumeToMount`