# Mount RAID SHR disk on Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid

I connected a RAID disk to my computer on Ubuntu 20.04. The disk comes from a Synology NAS containing two disks configured as RAID.

I would like to back up some data from the disk, bu when I plug the disk in my computer, I'm not able to mount it, even with the gnome-disk-utility. I see the disk, but I can't mount it. here what I get:

[image]

How do I mount the disk to access the data? Should I plug the two disks?

Edit: I need to copy >1To of data from the disk to my computer, this is why I plugged the disk to avoid over loading the network. Disk is not encrypted, disk are RAID SHR.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the type of RAID your Synology Box was using, whether the RAID partitions are encrypted, and perhaps what your ultimate goal is? (Backing up data can be done with an intact Synology, so why dismantle it?) This will make it easier to know where to start with this question, as the answer could be rather involved ...

Comment: @matigo I updated the question.

Comment: If you do not know the type of RAID, then I would suggest putting the disk back in your Synology and using the network to carry the data, as that's what networks are designed to do. 1200GB @ 100Mbit = 28h 38m. 1200GB @ 1Gbit = 02h 52m. While "impatience is a virtue" in recent years, it's not worth completely mucking up your RAID array and losing everything.

Comment: @matigo. Thank you for the advice, but that's not the answer to my question. What I exactly want to do is a diff between one folder on the NAS disk and a copy on my local computer.

Comment: If you don’t know whether you’re using RAID0, RAID1, JBOD, or some BTRFS pool, then there’s no possible way anyone can answer your question in a manner that does not expose your data to catastrophic failure. I would rather keep my mouth shut and be considered a fool than to invest an hour writing a detailed answer that removes all doubt 

Comment: @matigo How could I know if I'm using RAID0, RAID1 ...

Comment: @matigo This is RAID SHR, I updated the question.

Comment: If it's RAID SHR, [someone had a similar question a few years ago](https://askubuntu.com/q/882121/1222991). Read both the question and the answer carefully. That may get you what you're looking for, but pay attention to the caveats, because it may result in problems if you skip steps.